# ReactJs: transitions in nested elements

Tags: animation, nested, reactjs, transition

I am new in ReactJs, developed multi nested folders browsing - what I mean is here - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7804/ .

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
      var List = React.createClass({
         getInitialState: function() {
            return {data:this.props.data};
        },
        onClickHandler: function (nodeName, i, e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var newState = this.state.data[nodeName][i].isExpanded?false:true;
            this.state.data[nodeName][i].isExpanded = newState;
            this.setState(this.state);
        },
        render: function() {

            var getList = function(nodes) {

                var listElements = nodes.map(function(node) {
                    return this.state.data[node].map(function (nodeData,i) {
                        var subList = null;
                        if(nodeData.isExpanded) {
                            subList = getList(nodeData.nodes);
                        }
                        return (<li  onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this, node, i)}>
                                {nodeData.label}{subList}
                            </li>);
                    }.bind(this));
                }.bind(this));

                return <ul>{listElements}</ul>;

            }.bind(this);


            return  getList(['root'], 0);
        }
    });



    var data = {
        root:[{
            label:'1',
            nodes: ['a','b']
        },{
            label:'2',
            nodes: ['d','e']
        }],
        a:[{
            label:'label a',
            nodes: ['c']
        }],
        b:[{
            label: 'label b',
            nodes:[]
        }],
        c:[{
            label: 'label c',
            nodes: []
        }],
        d:[{
            label: 'label d',
            nodes: []
        }],
        e:[{
            label: 'label e',
            nodes: []
        }]
    }
    React.render(<List data={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

All works nicely, hides and shows nested nodes. Now I want to wrap everything in CSSTransitionGroup to have transitions on hide and show. I was reading all about it here - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html and I got really confused how I should implement that in this multi nested nodes scenario.

Can someone  point me in to right direction?

Thanks. 
Tomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after x amount of painful, but joyful hours I found solution.
Updated here - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7856/

Why it was painful? Well it took long to figure out that ReactCSSTransitionGroup needs to be always in the DOM even if I am not adding nested .

Also I need to nest ReactCSSTransitionGroup same way as  is nested as, ReactCSSTransitionGroup creates special  element which children will be animated.

And ReactCSSTransitionGroup cares just about animating top level children. So if you **ONLY** changing state(removing/adding) nested div but leaving its parent which **is child** of ReactCSSTransitionGroup it will not animate.

code:

```
    var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
    var List = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
        return {data:this.props.data};
    },
    onClickHandler: function (nodeName, i, e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var newState = this.state.data[nodeName][i].isExpanded?false:true;
        this.state.data[nodeName][i].isExpanded = newState;
        this.setState(this.state);
    },
    render: function() {

        var getList = function(nodes) {

            var listElements = nodes.map(function(node) {
                return this.state.data[node].map(function (nodeData,i) {
                    var subList = '';
                    if(nodeData.isExpanded) {
                        subList = getList(nodeData.nodes);
                    }
                    return (<li  onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this, node, i)}>
                            {nodeData.label}
                            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
                                {subList}
                            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                        </li>);
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));

            return <ul key={nodes.join('_')}>{listElements}</ul>;

        }.bind(this);


        return  getList(['root'], 0);
    }
});



var data = {
    root:[{
        label:'1',
        nodes: ['a','b']
    },{
        label:'2',
        nodes: ['d','e']
    }],
    a:[{
        label:'label a',
        nodes: ['c']
    }],
    b:[{
        label: 'label b',
        nodes:[]
    }],
    c:[{
        label: 'label c',
        nodes: []
    }],
    d:[{
        label: 'label d',
        nodes: []
    }],
    e:[{
        label: 'label e',
        nodes: []
    }]
}
React.render(<List data={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: thanks, so if I understand I can put react-transition-group anywhere in my application on the component I want to animate then it will automatically create top level children to animate that it?